# the imported project does not work in android studio

Tags: android, import, android-studio

I just downloaded the https://github.com/baugarten/Android-Image-Edit from git hub but when i import project i have a lot of errors.i think i should import the library's but i don't know which one
these are some errors

```
Error:(7, 27) error: package org.apache.sanselan does not exist
Error:(60, 22) error: package com.google.ads does not exist
Error:(136, 13) error: cannot find symbol class AdView
Error:(179, 40) error: package AdSize does not exist
Error:(666, 46) error: cannot find symbol variable ExifTagConstants
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors like *"cannot find symbol"* is because this class is not found on your repository. Find and add them.
The errors like *"...does not exist"* is because you should import these libraries into your project.